# How to read all tables from a SQLite database and store as datasets/variables in R?

Tags: sql, r, database, sqlite, dataset

I have a large SQLite database with many tables. I have established a connection to this database in RStudio using RSQLite and DBI packages. (I have named this database `db`)

```r
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
```

At the moment I have to read in all the tables and assign them a name manually. For example:

```r
country <- dbReadTable(db, "country")
date <- dbReadTable(db, "date")
#...and so on
```

You can see this can be a very time-consuming process if you were to have many tables.

So I was wondering if it is possible to create a new function or using existing functions (e.g. `lapply()` ?) to complete this more efficiently and essentially speed up this process?

Any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mindsets:

1. All tables/data into one named-list:

   ```r
   alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm = dbListTables(db)), dbReadTable, conn = db)
   ```

   The benefit of this is that if the tables have similar meaning, then you can use `lapply` to apply the same function to each. Another benefit is that all data from one database are stored together.

   See [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for working on a list-of-frames.
2. If you want them as actual variables in the global (or enclosing) environment, then take the previous `alldat`, and

   ```r
   ign <- list2env(alldat, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   ```

   The return value from `list2env` is the environment that we passed to `list2env`, so it's not incredibly useful in this context (though it is useful other times). The only reason I capture it into `ign` is to reduce the clutter on the console ... which is minor. `list2env` works primarily in side-effect, so the return value in this case is not critical.

Comment: perfect! exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dbListTables()` to generate a character vector of all your table names in your SQLite database and use `lapply()` to import them into R efficiently. I would first check you are able to import all the tables in your database into memory.

Below is an reproducible example of this:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(db, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbWriteTable(db, "iris", iris)
db_tbls <- dbListTables(db)

tbl_list <- lapply(db_tbls, dbReadTable, conn = db)
tbl_list <- setNames(tbl_list, db_tbls)

dbDisconnect(db)

> lapply(tbl_list, head)
$iris
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

$mtcars
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do exactly the same, but only get the first few rows of each table?

Comment: one option is instead of using `dbReadTable` in `lapply(...)` you can use `dbGetQuery` and use a SQL statement to get N rows from each table